# Compiling with GLFW3, linker errors 'undefined reference'

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opengl, glfw

Having a minimal example using `GLFW3`:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    glfwInit();
}
```

...results in a ton of linker errors: (small excerpt)

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CFArrayAppendValue", referenced from:
      _addJoystickElement in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFArrayApplyFunction", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticks in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
      _addJoystickElement in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFArrayCreateMutable", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticks in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)

  ...

  "_objc_msgSend_fixup", referenced from:
  l_objc_msgSend_fixup_count in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  l_objc_msgSend_fixup_objectAtIndex_ in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  l_objc_msgSend_fixup_objectForKey_ in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  l_objc_msgSend_fixup_release in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  l_objc_msgSend_fixup_alloc in libglfw3.a(nsgl_context.m.o)
  l_objc_msgSend_fixup_release in libglfw3.a(nsgl_context.m.o)
  ...
```

`OpenGL.framework` and `libglfw3.a` are both linked.

[image]

What is the reason for this? Compiling a `glfw2` application before worked like a charm.

Comment: glfw3 probably made the switch from Carbon (C) to Cocoa (Objective C) for its render context / window management interface. With each version of OS X, less and less core OS functionality is exposed through the Carbon interface and it gets worse if you are writing a 64-bit Carbon-based application. Try adding the Cocoa framework to your build configuration.

Comment: Did you solve the problem somehow?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi I had to link to the `IOKit`, `CoreVideo` and `Cocoa` frameworks. See the answers to this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Mac OS X, glfw3 uses Cocoa (NSGL) for its OpenGL context management. glfw2 used Carbon (CGL/AGL, depending on fullscreen or windowed mode).

NSGL is more robust, but it is built upon an Objective C framework (Cocoa). In order for your software to work correctly with glfw3, you should include the Cocoa framework.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, that did the trick. Additionally to the `Cocoa` framework, the `IOKit` framework was also required though.

Comment: I also just had this issue and in addition to the `Cocoa` and `IOKit` I also had to add the `CoreVideo` kit and then it was working for me.

Comment: @TrevorPeyton: Ah, I see. When I originally wrote this answer, it was to explain only the unresolved symbols in the original question. It appears there are more dependencies introduced with GLFW3 than I originally thought.

Answer (score 27):

[If you are using the static library version of GLFW, add it and the **Cocoa**, **OpenGL**, **IOKit** and **CoreVideo** frameworks to the project as dependencies.](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build.html)

Comment: Thanks. Just for reference, I'll post the command line that just did the trick on my system: `gcc -Iglfw3/include/ -Lglfw3/lib/ -lglfw3 -framework OpenGL -framework Cocoa -framework IOKit -framework CoreVideo main.c`.

Comment: In my case, I only needed -l glfw3 and that solved it.

Comment: In keys if someone is interesting of using [GLFW with Swift 3](https://github.com/ValeriyKliuk/GLFW)

Comment: I added everything suggested *except* OpenGL (since I am building w Vulkan) and it worked.