# Installing libhand on OSX 10.9.4

Tags: macos, makefile, cmake, libhand

I tried to build libhand http://www.libhand.org/ v0.9 for OSX, the cmake command works fine, but as soon as I run the make command I get the following error

```
Scanning dependencies of target hand_utils [  4%] Building CXX object
source/CMakeFiles/hand_utils.dir/mac_app_loop.mm.o [  8%] Building CXX
object source/CMakeFiles/hand_utils.dir/error_handling.cc.o [ 12%]
Building CXX object source/CMakeFiles/hand_utils.dir/file_dialog.cc.o

/Users/temp/libhand-0.9/hand_cpp/source/file_dialog.cc:113:3: error: 
      use of undeclared identifier 'unlink'; did you mean 'inline'?   unlink(temp_cmd_fname.c_str());   ^

/Users/temp/libhand-0.9/hand_cpp/source/file_dialog.cc:114:3: error: 
      use of undeclared identifier 'unlink'; did you mean 'inline'?   unlink(temp_out_fname.c_str());   ^

2 errors generated. make[2]: ***
[source/CMakeFiles/hand_utils.dir/file_dialog.cc.o] Error 1 make[1]:
*** [source/CMakeFiles/hand_utils.dir/all] Error 2 make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I couldn't find any information on what to do and I am not sure what extra information I could provide to debug this error.

I also tried looking for a homebrew install but no luck.

Thanks for the help

Edit:

As suggested adding "ustd.h" did help, the ptr erros were resolved by adding std::ptr. The new error is:

```
Linking CXX executable pose_designer Undefined symbols for
architecture x86_64:   "_CFArrayAppendValue", referenced from:
      Ogre::OSXGLSupport::addConfig() in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXGLSupport.o)  
"_CFArrayCreateMutable", referenced from:
      Ogre::OSXGLSupport::addConfig() in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXGLSupport.o)   "_CFArrayGetCount",
referenced from:
      Ogre::OSXGLSupport::addConfig() in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXGLSupport.o)  
"_CFArrayGetValueAtIndex", referenced from:
      Ogre::OSXGLSupport::addConfig() in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXGLSupport.o)   "_CFArraySortValues",
referenced from:
      Ogre::OSXGLSupport::addConfig() in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXGLSupport.o)   "_CFBooleanGetValue",
referenced from:
      Ogre::OSXGLSupport::_getDictionaryBoolean(__CFDictionary const*, void const*) in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXGLSupport.o)  
"_CFBundleCopyBundleURL", referenced from:
      Ogre::macFrameworksPath() in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)
      Ogre::macPluginPath() in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)
      Ogre::macBundlePath() in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)   "_CFBundleCopyResourceURL", referenced from:
      Ogre::mac_loadExeBundle(char const*) in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)   "_CFBundleCreate", referenced from:
      Ogre::mac_loadExeBundle(char const*) in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)   "_CFBundleGetBundleWithIdentifier",
referenced from:
      Ogre::mac_loadExeBundle(char const*) in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)  
"_CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName", referenced from:
      Ogre::mac_getBundleSym(__CFBundle*, char const*) in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)   "_CFBundleGetMainBundle", referenced
from:
      Ogre::mac_loadExeBundle(char const*) in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)
      Ogre::macFrameworksPath() in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)
      Ogre::macPluginPath() in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)
      Ogre::macBundlePath() in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)   "_CFBundleLoadExecutable", referenced from:
      Ogre::mac_loadExeBundle(char const*) in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)   "_CFDictionaryGetValue", referenced
from:
      Ogre::OSXGLSupport::_getDictionaryBoolean(__CFDictionary const*, void const*) in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXGLSupport.o)
      Ogre::OSXGLSupport::_getDictionaryLong(__CFDictionary const*, void const*) in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXGLSupport.o)  
"_CFNumberGetValue", referenced from:
      Ogre::OSXGLSupport::_getDictionaryLong(__CFDictionary const*, void const*) in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXGLSupport.o)  
"_CFRelease", referenced from:
      Ogre::mac_loadExeBundle(char const*) in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)
      Ogre::mac_getBundleSym(__CFBundle*, char const*) in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)
      Ogre::macFrameworksPath() in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)
      Ogre::macPluginPath() in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)
      Ogre::macBundlePath() in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)
      Ogre::OSXGLSupport::addConfig() in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXGLSupport.o)  
"_CFStringCreateWithCString", referenced from:
      Ogre::mac_loadExeBundle(char const*) in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)
      Ogre::mac_getBundleSym(__CFBundle*, char const*) in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)   "_CFStringCreateWithSubstring",
referenced from:
      Ogre::mac_loadExeBundle(char const*) in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)  
"_CFStringGetFileSystemRepresentation", referenced from:
      Ogre::macFrameworksPath() in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)
      Ogre::macPluginPath() in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)
      Ogre::macBundlePath() in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)   "_CFStringGetLength", referenced from:
      Ogre::mac_loadExeBundle(char const*) in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)   "_CFStringHasSuffix", referenced
from:
      Ogre::mac_loadExeBundle(char const*) in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)   "_CFURLCopyFileSystemPath",
referenced from:
      Ogre::macFrameworksPath() in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)
      Ogre::macPluginPath() in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)
      Ogre::macBundlePath() in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)   "_CGDisplayCopyAllDisplayModes", referenced from:
      Ogre::OSXGLSupport::addConfig() in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXGLSupport.o)  
"_CGDisplayIDToOpenGLDisplayMask", referenced from:
      Ogre::OSXGLSupport::addConfig() in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXGLSupport.o)
      Ogre::OSXCocoaWindow::create(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&,
unsigned int, unsigned int, bool,
std::__1::map<std::__1::basic_string<char,
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >,
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,
std::__1::allocator<char> >,
std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char,
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >,
Ogre::STLAllocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char,
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const,
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,
std::__1::allocator<char> > >,
Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy<(Ogre::MemoryCategory)0> > > const*) in
libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindow.o)  
"_CGDisplayModeGetHeight", referenced from:
      Ogre::OSXGLSupport::addConfig() in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXGLSupport.o)
      Ogre::OSXGLSupport::_compareModes(void const*, void const*, void*) in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXGLSupport.o)  
"_CGDisplayModeGetIOFlags", referenced from:
      Ogre::OSXGLSupport::addConfig() in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXGLSupport.o)  
"_CGDisplayModeGetRefreshRate", referenced from:
      Ogre::OSXGLSupport::_compareModes(void const*, void const*, void*) in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXGLSupport.o)  
"_CGDisplayModeGetWidth", referenced from:
      Ogre::OSXGLSupport::addConfig() in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXGLSupport.o)
      Ogre::OSXGLSupport::_compareModes(void const*, void const*, void*) in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXGLSupport.o)  
"_CGMainDisplayID", referenced from:
      Ogre::OSXGLSupport::addConfig() in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXGLSupport.o)
      Ogre::OSXCocoaWindow::create(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&,
unsigned int, unsigned int, bool,
std::__1::map<std::__1::basic_string<char,
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >,
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,
std::__1::allocator<char> >,
std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char,
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >,
Ogre::STLAllocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char,
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const,
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,
std::__1::allocator<char> > >,
Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy<(Ogre::MemoryCategory)0> > > const*) in
libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindow.o)  
"_CGWindowLevelForKey", referenced from:
      Ogre::OSXCocoaWindow::_setWindowParameters() in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindow.o)   "_NSApp",
referenced from:
      MacAppLoopPrivate::Setup(double) in libhand_utils.a(mac_app_loop.mm.o)
      MacAppLoop::Run() in libhand_utils.a(mac_app_loop.mm.o)
      MacAppLoopPrivate::Run() in libhand_utils.a(mac_app_loop.mm.o)
      -[MacAppDelegate appShutdown] in libhand_utils.a(mac_app_loop.mm.o)
      Ogre::ConfigDialog::display() in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)
      -[OgreConfigWindowDelegate windowShouldClose:] in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)
      -[OgreConfigWindowDelegate cancelButtonPressed:] in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)
      ...   "_NSApplicationLoad", referenced from:
      -[OgreConfigWindowDelegate init] in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)
      Ogre::OSXCocoaWindow::create(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&,
unsigned int, unsigned int, bool,
std::__1::map<std::__1::basic_string<char,
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >,
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,
std::__1::allocator<char> >,
std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char,
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >,
Ogre::STLAllocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char,
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const,
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,
std::__1::allocator<char> > >,
Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy<(Ogre::MemoryCategory)0> > > const*) in
libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindow.o)
      -[OgreView initWithFrame:] in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaView.o)  
"_NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains", referenced from:
      Ogre::macCachePath() in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)   "_NSTemporaryDirectory", referenced from:
      Ogre::macTempFileName() in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)   "_NSZeroPoint", referenced from:
      Ogre::OSXCocoaWindow::OSXCocoaWindow() in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindow.o)
      Ogre::OSXCocoaWindow::_setWindowParameters() in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindow.o)  
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSApplication", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_NSApplication_$__suppressUnimplementedActionWarning
in libhand_utils.a(mac_app_loop.mm.o)
      objc-class-ref in libhand_utils.a(mac_app_loop.mm.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSArray", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAutoreleasePool", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libhand_utils.a(mac_app_loop.mm.o)
      objc-class-ref in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)
      objc-class-ref in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindow.o)  
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSBox", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSBundle", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSButton", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSDictionary", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)
      objc-class-ref in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXGLSupport.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFileManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSImage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSImageView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMenu", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libhand_utils.a(mac_app_loop.mm.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMenuItem", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libhand_utils.a(mac_app_loop.mm.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMutableArray", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSNotificationCenter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindowDelegate.o)  
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MacAppDelegate in libhand_utils.a(mac_app_loop.mm.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_OgreConfigWindowDelegate in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_OSXCocoaWindowDelegate in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindowDelegate.o)  
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSOpenGLContext", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindow.o)
      objc-class-ref in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaContext.o)  
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSOpenGLPixelFormat", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindow.o)  
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSPopUpButton", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSProcessInfo", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libhand_utils.a(mac_app_loop.mm.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSScreen", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXGLSupport.o)
      objc-class-ref in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindow.o)  
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSScrollView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSString", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)
      objc-class-ref in libOgreMainStatic.a(macUtils.o)
      objc-class-ref in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXGLSupport.o)
      objc-class-ref in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindow.o)  
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSTableColumn", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSTableView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSTextField", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSTimer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libhand_utils.a(mac_app_loop.mm.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSView", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_OgreView in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaView.o)  
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSWindow", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_OgreWindow in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindow.o)  
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MacAppDelegate in libhand_utils.a(mac_app_loop.mm.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_OgreConfigWindowDelegate in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_OgreWindow in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindow.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_OSXCocoaWindowDelegate in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindowDelegate.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_OgreView in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaView.o)  
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSView", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_OgreView in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaView.o)  
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSWindow", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_OgreWindow in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindow.o)  
"___CFConstantStringClassReference", referenced from:
      CFString in libhand_utils.a(mac_app_loop.mm.o)
      CFString in libhand_utils.a(mac_app_loop.mm.o)
      CFString in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)
      CFString in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)
      CFString in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)
      CFString in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)
      CFString in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)
      ...   "__objc_empty_cache", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MacAppDelegate in libhand_utils.a(mac_app_loop.mm.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MacAppDelegate in libhand_utils.a(mac_app_loop.mm.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_OgreConfigWindowDelegate in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_OgreConfigWindowDelegate in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_OgreWindow in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindow.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_OgreWindow in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindow.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_OSXCocoaWindowDelegate in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindowDelegate.o)
      ...   "__objc_empty_vtable", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_OgreConfigWindowDelegate in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_OgreConfigWindowDelegate in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_OgreWindow in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindow.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_OgreWindow in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindow.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_OSXCocoaWindowDelegate in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindowDelegate.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_OSXCocoaWindowDelegate in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindowDelegate.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_OgreView in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaView.o)
      ...   "_kCFAllocatorDefault", referenced from:
      Ogre::OSXGLSupport::addConfig() in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXGLSupport.o)   "_objc_msgSend",
referenced from:
      MacAppLoop::~MacAppLoop() in libhand_utils.a(mac_app_loop.mm.o)
      MacAppLoop::~MacAppLoop() in libhand_utils.a(mac_app_loop.mm.o)
      MacAppLoop::~MacAppLoop() in libhand_utils.a(mac_app_loop.mm.o)
      MacAppLoopPrivate::~MacAppLoopPrivate() in libhand_utils.a(mac_app_loop.mm.o)
      MacAppLoopPrivate::Setup(double) in libhand_utils.a(mac_app_loop.mm.o)
      MacAppLoop::Run() in libhand_utils.a(mac_app_loop.mm.o)
      MacAppLoopPrivate::Run() in libhand_utils.a(mac_app_loop.mm.o)
      ...   "_objc_msgSendSuper2", referenced from:
      -[MacAppDelegate initWithPrivateLoop:] in libhand_utils.a(mac_app_loop.mm.o)
      -[MacAppDelegate dealloc] in libhand_utils.a(mac_app_loop.mm.o)
      -[OgreConfigWindowDelegate init] in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)
      -[OgreConfigWindowDelegate dealloc] in libOgreMainStatic.a(OgreConfigDialog.o)
      -[OSXCocoaWindowDelegate initWithNSWindow:ogreWindow:] in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindowDelegate.o)
      -[OSXCocoaWindowDelegate dealloc] in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindowDelegate.o)
      -[OgreView initWithFrame:] in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaView.o)
      ...   "_objc_msgSend_stret", referenced from:
      Ogre::OSXCocoaWindow::create(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&,
unsigned int, unsigned int, bool,
std::__1::map<std::__1::basic_string<char,
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >,
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,
std::__1::allocator<char> >,
std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char,
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >,
Ogre::STLAllocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char,
std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const,
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,
std::__1::allocator<char> > >,
Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy<(Ogre::MemoryCategory)0> > > const*) in
libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindow.o)
      Ogre::OSXCocoaWindow::createNewWindow(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,
std::__1::allocator<char> >) in
libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindow.o)
      Ogre::OSXCocoaWindow::getWidth() const in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindow.o)
      Ogre::OSXCocoaWindow::getHeight() const in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindow.o)
      Ogre::OSXCocoaWindow::reposition(int, int) in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindow.o)
      Ogre::OSXCocoaWindow::resize(unsigned int, unsigned int) in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindow.o)
      Ogre::OSXCocoaWindow::windowResized() in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXCocoaWindow.o)
      ... ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
invocation) make[2]: *** [source/pose_designer] Error 1 make[1]: ***
[source/CMakeFiles/pose_designer.dir/all] Error 2 make: *** [all]
Error 2
```

EDIT:

After adding the cocoa or carbon framework it builds fine. This can be done by editing the CMakeLists.txt file and adding the lines:

FIND_LIBRARY(COCOA_LIBRARY Cocoa)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${COCOA_LIBRARY})

and adding a line the line: ${COCOA_LIBRARY} to the TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES

Thanks again to Etan for the hint.

Comment: Does adding `#include <unistd>` to the top of that file help?

Comment: Adding #include <unistd.h> did help, now the error says:


 error: 
      unknown type name 'shared_ptr'
  shared_ptr<GLPlugin> gl_plugin_;

Is this related to the unistd.h header ?

Comment: I worked around the shared_ptr issue by just adding std::shared_ptr. The new error is:

Linking CXX executable pose_designer
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CFArrayAppendValue", referenced from:
      Ogre::OSXGLSupport::addConfig() in libRenderSystem_GLStatic.a(OgreOSXGLSupport.o)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391487 seems like it might be relevant at this point. But ultimately I think you need to go complain to the libhand people that their build is very fragile and depends on some assumptions that don't hold true everywhere.

Comment: how do I go about including a framework in the makefile?

Comment: Not even the slightest clue. Sorry. Not an OS X person.