# Importing Libraries into QTCreator

Tags: qt, opengl, build, cmake

I am creating an OpenGL project in QT Creator, and would like to import GLFW and potentially other libraries later on.
I compiled and imported GLFW and was able to import it via
`#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>`

Qt Creator was even able to autofill the glfw methods. However, when I attempted to call one of them (e.g. `glfwInit();`, the compiler threw me the following error:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CFArrayAppendValue", referenced from:
      _addJoystickElement in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFArrayApplyFunction", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticks in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
      _addJoystickElement in libglfw3.a(iokit_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFArrayCreateMutable", referenced from:
```

... etc

I'm assuming it was unable to find the implementation of these methods.

**I imported GLFW through the following procedure:**

 
1. I used CMake to build a Unix Script. 
2. I ran "make" in terminal on the generated makefile. This created a file called "libglfw3.a" 
3. I imported the library into the project through QT, setting the Library as libglfw3.a and include path as "mypath/include/" (this folder contains another folder called GLFW, which contains glfw3.h).

QT Creator then entered the following into the QT project file.

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/glfw-3.1.1/src/release/ -lglfw3
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/glfw-3.1.1/src/debug/ -lglfw3
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/glfw-3.1.1/src/ -lglfw3
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/glfw-3.1.1/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/glfw-3.1.1/include
win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/glfw-3.1.1/src/release/libglfw3.a
else:win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/glfw-3.1.1/src/debug/libglfw3.a
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/glfw-3.1.1/src/release/glfw3.lib
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/glfw-3.1.1/src/debug/glfw3.lib
else:unix: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/glfw-3.1.1/src/libglfw3.a
```

Help would be greatly appreciated. I've spent at least 10 hours trying to figure out how to import a GL library into QT Creator, but all I can find are CMake tutorials for XCode, Visual Studio, etc.

I would ideally like to this by just modifying the QT .pro file, because I don't have experience with CMake, but if there are no alternatives, that's fine.
I'm developing with QT creator on Mac 10.10.15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone's curious, I figured it out.

I followed the procedure here: [Compiling with GLFW3, linker errors 'undefined reference'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391487/compiling-with-glfw3-linker-errors-undefined-reference)

I didn't at first think this was relevant because it was specifically referring to building on XCode, but it turns out you have to do the exact same thing with QT Creator.
right click the project, Import Library -> System/Library/Frameworks -> and import Cocoa, CoreVideo, and IOKit.

My .pro file had the following lines added to them after I did all that

```
mac: LIBS += -framework Cocoa
else:unix|win32: LIBS += -lCocoa

mac: LIBS += -framework IOKit
else:unix|win32: LIBS += -lIOKit
```

mac: LIBS += -framework CoreVideo
else:unix|win32: LIBS += -lCoreVideo